# Does a DC Current charge a DISCHARGED capacitor and does the current pass throug the capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, dc, charge

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fddAQs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Like I said, does a DC Current charge a **discharged** capacitor and does the current pass through the capacitor and feed a resistor? (The values in the given schematic are not real.)

Comment: Yes, it can and will. Passes through it? Well, sort of.

Comment: through the capacitor itself?

Comment: Mathematically - yes. But physically - it will take charges from one plate into the battery and put the charges to the other plate from the battery.

Comment: if we place a light bulb instead of resistor what does happen?

Comment: It will light up and slowly fade until the cap is charged.

Comment: And when the capacitor is charged, it blocks the DC? Right?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ppWBwZS4e7A?t=1009

Comment: Well, not if it's a zero-farad capacitor...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is kinda. The current will "flow" through the capacitor and go through the resistor. What is happening is that as the capacitor is getting charged, the charge in the capacitor is displaced by the incoming electrons so it comes out the capacitor and flows through.
For better detail, you should read this answer I found on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-current-flow-through-a-capacitor).

Answer (score 2):

It charges a capacitor, yet the current which flows through it is a displacement current. If you supply the circuit you drew (and of course select some nonzero value for both capacitor and resistor) with say, a DC battery and the capacitor is fully discharged (0 Coulomb), then the circuit will charge the capacitor with an exponential curve for both current and voltage: voltage by a positive yet decreasing \$\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$, and current by a negative yet increasing \$\dfrac{di}{dt}\$. The current flowing through the capacitor is the same flowing through the resistor, so it will dissipate energy as long as there is current flowing.